# Javascript user request layer

Tags: user-interface, javascript

I am currently writing a compatibility layer between browsers and for this I need to ask the user to confirm an action. Currently the only standard way in JavaScript to do this is `window.confirm` which is synchronous and I do not want to block the whole site. So I would be searching for a library which can display a asynchronous browser-like request (e.g. the ones they use for *Geolocation*).

EDIT: And similar to the native one I do not need/want the user interaction to be modal. Just displaying and reacting on user input that is all.

I remember having seen such sites, but cannot remember where.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

As a bonus it would be great if it would work an look like the native ones in *IE*, *FF* and *Opera*.

Answer (score 2):

the [jQueryUI library](http://jqueryui.com/) has a [dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal) plugin that can be made modal. Since it is JS, it does not block the rest of the page execution.

Comment: Thanks, that is going in the right direction. I would prefer something lighter than _jQueryUI_ though.

Comment: I agree that it can be a bit heavy for some sites, but there are _lots_ of ways to slim down the payload, including using a CDN (like the free one Google offers), compressing any libraries you host, and only including the jqUI plugins you need.